# How can I share an updated values in dictionary among different process?

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, serial-port, multiprocessing

I am newbe here and also in Python. I have a question about dictionaries and multiprocessing. I want to run this part of the code on the second core of my Raspberry Pi (on first is running GUI application). So, I created a dictionary (keys(20) + array with the length of 256 for each of this key - script below is just short example). I initialized this dictionary in a separate script and put all values inside this dictionary on zero. Script table1.py (this dictionary should be available from both cores)

```
diction = {}
diction['FrameID']= [0]*10
diction['Flag']= ["Z"]*10
```

In the second script (should run on the second core), I read the values that I get from the serial port and put/set them in this dictionary (parsing + conversion) according to the appropriate place. Since I get much information through a serial port, the information is changing all the time. Script Readmode.py

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import time
import serial
import table1

def replace_all(text, dic):
for i, j in dic.iteritems():
    text = text.replace(i, j)
return text
def hexTobin(hex_num):
scale = 16 ## equals to hexadecimal
num_of_bits = len(hex_num)*4
bin_num = bin(int(hex_num, scale))[2:].zfill(num_of_bits) #hex to binary
return bin_num

def readSerial():
port = "/dev/ttyAMA0"
baudrate = 115200
ser = serial.Serial(port, baudrate, bytesize=8, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits=1, xonxoff=False, rtscts=False)
line = []
for x in xrange(1):
    ser.write(":AAFF:AA\r\n:F1\r\n")        # new           
    while True:
        for c in ser.read():
            line.append(c)
            a=''.join(line[-2:])
            if a == '\r\n':
                b=''.join(line)
                print("what I get:" + b) 
                c=b[b.rfind(":"):len(b)] #string between last ":" start delimiter and stop delimiter
                reps = {':':'', '\r\n':''} #throw away start and stop delimiter
                txt = replace_all(c, reps)   
                print("hex num: " + txt) 
                bina_num=hexTobin(txt) # convert hex to bin
                print("bin num: " + bina_num)
                ssbit = bina_num[:3] # first three bits 
                print("select first three bits: " + ssbit)
                abit=int(ssbit,2) # binary to integer 
                if abit == 5:
                    table1.diction['FrameID'][0]=abit
                    if abit == 7:
                        table1.diction['FrameID'][5]=abit         
                        print("int num: ",abit)
                        print(table1.diction)
                        line = []
                        break
                        ser.close()

p1=Process(target=readSerial)
p1.start()
```

During that time I want to read information in this dictionary and use them in another process. But When I try to read that values there are all zero.

My question is how to create a dictionary that will be available for both process and can be updated based on data get from serial port? 
Thank you for your answer in advance.

Comment: Since the problem is probably in your code we'll need to see it to answer. Ideally in a short stripped down version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, when you start two different scripts, even if they import some common modules, they share nothing (except the code). If two scripts both `import table1`, then they both have their own instance of the `table1` module and therefore their own instance of the `table1.diction` variable.

If you think about it, it *has* to be like that.  Otherwise all Python scripts would share the same `sys.stdout`, for example.  So, more or less nothing is shared between two different scripts executing at the same time.

The `multiprocessing` module lets you create more than one process from the same single script.  So you'll need to merge your GUI and your reading function into the same script.  But then you can do what you want.  Your code will look something like this:

```
import multiprocessing

# create shared dictionary sd

p1=Process(target=readSerial, args = (sd,)
p1.start()

# create the GUI behaviour you want
```

But hang on a minute.  This won't work either.  Because when the `Process` is created it starts a new instance of the Python interpreter and creates all its own instances again, just like starting a new script.  So even now, *by default*, nothing in `readSerial` will be shared with the GUI process.

But fortunately the `multiprocessing` module provides some explicit techniques to share data between the processes.  There is more than one way to do that, but here is one that works:

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def readSerial(d):
    d["test"] = []
    for i in range(100):
        l = d["test"]
        l.append(i)
        d["test"] = l
        time.sleep(1)

def doGUI(d):
    while True:
        print(d)
        time.sleep(.5)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    with multiprocessing.Manager() as manager:
        sd = manager.dict()

        p = multiprocessing.Process(target=readSerial, args=(sd,))
        p.start()

        doGUI(sd)
```

You'll notice that the append to the list in the `readSerial` function is a bit odd.  That is because the dictionary object we are working with here is not a normal dictionary.  It's actually a dictionary *proxy* that conceals a pipe used to send the data between the two processes.  When I append to the list inside the dictionary the proxy needs to be notified (by assigning to the dictionary) so it knows to send the updated data across the pipe.  That is why we need the assignment (rather than simply directly mutating the list inside the dictionary).  For more on this look at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/multiprocessing.html).

Comment: Could you please provide me with information how can I use this for dictionary which has more keys and each of them have array of values (like in my example)?

Comment: Not sure why that is any different?  The shared dictionary is a proxy but you can use it like a dictionary: changes you make to it are passed back to the other process,  I've added some more details to the answer but if you are still stuck, you need to show me which bit of code is still causing you a problem.

Comment: When I read data from serial port I want put them on the specified place. Example: I get frame with frameID (these IDs are always between 1 and 256) and additional information. I want to put these data always on same place, so if frameID is 124 I want to write all information about this frame on same place -> dict {['Flag'][123]} = 5, dict {['Dsc'][123]="on" and so on. In GUI i just call key and place in array that I want. I hope that this is understandable.

Comment: If I understand this correctly after each frame sends through a serial port, I add one additional place in the dictionary. So, if I get 1000 frames, I will have 1000 additional places (columns)? So, I need somehow limit that?

Comment: These questions are on a different topic. The question was how to share a dictionary between two processes. I suggest you put together the code you have so far and ask a different question if you are still stuck.